# Did Madara uchiha gave Might guy a new nick name or is he praising him?

Tags: naruto

We know that in the fight between Madara and Guy Madara declares he is the strongest taijutsu user is it nick name or is he praising him? We know Hanjo gave a nick name Sanin, and Minato nick named 'B' killer Bee.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Madara was not giving him as a new nickname.  He was *just* acknowledging the strength of Might Guy.